# App interface snapshot flashes briefly after terminating app from suspended state

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

How do I achieve my expected behaviour?

**Current behaviour**

Terminating app from a suspended state causes a brief flash of the last app snapshot taken by the OS.

The order of things rendering, following launching after suspended state termination:

1. Launch screen storyboard image
2. App snapshot of last visible screen - same as one in the home button initiated multitask menu
3. Root view controller with its initial view

**Expected behaviour**

An app NOT participating in state restoration, when it terminates, should launch with the default launch image. I would like that to happen.

The order of things rendering, following launching after suspended state termination:

1. Launch screen storyboard image
2. Root view controller with its initial view

**Replicated by**

1. Running the app
2. Pressing home button - moving app to background
3. Double-pressing home button - opening the multitask menu
4. Swiping the app up - to terminate it
5. Opening it again

**My settings**

My UIViewController subclasses are implemented completely programmatically - no Xib or Storyboards.

The LaunchScreen is a Storyboard.

I have explicitly made sure that the app does not engage in state restoration, with the following in the App Delegate:

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication,
      shouldSaveApplicationState coder: NSCoder) -> Bool { return false }

 func application(_ application: UIApplication, 
      shouldRestoreApplicationState coder: NSCoder) -> Bool { return false }
```

My Info.plist, has the setting:

```
 Application does not run in background = NO
```

**Notes**

I know about`ignoreSnapshotOnNextApplicationLaunch()` in a UIViewController's `encodeRestorableState(with coder: NSCoder)` method, and generally setting-up a restorable state - except that I do not want to have a restorable state.

I want the app to:

- relaunch from scratch whenever it terminates, for whatever reason
- return from a non-terminated suspended state
- not flash the app snapshot when launching after termination when suspended

Creating and destroying a view in App Delegate's `applicationWillResignActive(application:)` and `applicationDidBecomeActive(application:)` methods is also not helpful.

What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: There might be no way to control this. I find the snapshot behavior pretty crazy these days but unfortunately it isn't up to us. I'd file a bug with Apple if I were you.

Comment: As matt said its behaving very awkwardly in the recent os updates. I would recommend to put a blur view on the current viewController whenever your app goes to background(you have to remove it in resume) so that user will see this view or the launch screen instead of seeing the actual screen opened last time. At least this will give some kind of consistency.

Comment: I’ll probably file a bug or request. As I think there should be more explicit control of this aspect of operation. A few methods in the app delegate for general expected behaviour should suffice. Implementing an entire state restoration set of behaviours, just so you can ignore them, seems absurd.

Comment: Another idea I have is to keep the background suspended state active, by giving it a long-running menial background task. Thus triggering the `applicationWillTerminate(application:)` when the OS terminates from the suspended state. But I fear Apple or the phone's battery may not like this.